# How can I convert zip file to input stream without file path?

Tags: java, path, inputstream

I am writing a rest api method. I have to get a zip file, then read the data in that file and write it to the database. But I have to achieve this without writing or extracting the zip file in the local. So I can't use the file path. How can I access the file?

I tried to directly convert the file to inputstream with the following method. But it cannot find the file.
(java.io.IOException: Couldn't find file /zipFile.zip)

```
InputStream getZipFileContentAsInputStream(@Nonnull String fileName) throws IOException {
    if (!fileName.startsWith("/")) {
        fileName = "/" + fileName;      // NOSONAR This "/" is portable, it's inside a JAR.
    }
    val inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
    if (inputStream == null) {
        throw new IOException("Couldn't find file " + fileName);
    }

    if (fileName.endsWith(ZIP)) {
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            try (ZipInputStream bzIn = new ZipInputStream(inputStream)) {

                final byte[] buffer = new byte[ZIP_BUFFER_SIZE];
                int n;
                while (-1 != (n = bzIn.read(buffer))) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, n);
                }
                return new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
            }
        }
    } else {
        return inputStream;
    }
}
```

I send the file as the request param.

```
@PostMapping("/import/zip") public ResponseEntity<Object> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException, UnsupportedOperationException { ... }
```

Comment: Where does you zip file come from? Is is send as the request body or is it stored somewhere on disk?

Comment: If the zip file is a... file, then you have everything you need in [java.util.zip](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/zip/package-summary.html). If the zip file is itself a stream (say, from a network connection), it will get more complicated, as a zip file is not supposed to be read as stream (there is metadata at the end, for instance).

Comment: @YunusEmre Welcome to SO! please [edit] that info into your post instead of putting it in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved.

```
String unzip(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
    ByteArrayInputStream bufferedInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[ZIP_BUFFER_SIZE];

    try (ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(bufferedInputStream)) {
        ZipEntry zipEntry;

        while ((zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {

            if (!zipEntry.isDirectory()) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream fos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                int len;
                while ((len = zis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }

                String result = fos.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                
                fos.close();
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i have seen you cannot access the contents of the zip file directly from the zip file's input stream. So i did some kind of work around where you start by creating a temporary directory which will eventually be deleted by the OS, then read all the files in the uploaded zip file into that temporary folder. After reading all the files in the temporary folder you can then visit all the files in this folder and persist to you database. Here is the code example:

```
@PostMapping("upload")
public ResponseEntity<?> uploadFile(@RequestParam("multipartFile") MultipartFile multipartFile) throws IOException {

    File unzippedFolder = createTempZipFile(multipartFile);
    
    for (File file: unzippedFolder.listFiles()) { // May need to check if list is not null
        try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                // Here process you file
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
    }

    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}

private File createTempZipFile(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    File tempDir = Files.createTempDirectory("data").toFile();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    try(ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(file.getInputStream())) {
        ZipEntry zipEntry;

        while ((zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {

            if (!zipEntry.isDirectory()) {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(tempDir, zipEntry.getName()));

                int len;
                while ((len = zis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }
                fos.close();
            }
        }
    }

    return tempDir;
}
```